# Multiple task invocations running spring task scheduler on jboss 5.0.1 GA

Tags: spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, jboss5.x

I am running a Spring 3.1 MVC web application on JBoss 5.0.1 GA.  I am not using annotations.

I have a singeton that has a method that I want scheduled to run at a certain time of the day.

I have my task scheduler configured as follows:

```
<task:scheduler id="taskScheduler"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="taskScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="service" method="DoSomething" cron="* */10 * * * *"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="1"/>
```

Yet when I observe the trace logs, the method is being executed multiple times (on our qa server and prod server 8 times) instead of just once.

Is there something where the QuartzScheduler needs to be configured a certain way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the value `"* */10 * * * *"` of **cron** element is incorrect.

I cannot find an documentation for `*/10` on http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

The `/` introduces an increment from a value, where as `*` represents all values so `*/10` in the minutes does not make sense.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html

It's the sequence for every 10 minutes.

Comment: Besides the format of the cron sequence isn't the problem.  It executes every 10 minutes as expected.  As I mentioned above, the problem isn't when  the problem is the number of times it executes at the scheduled time.

Comment: The Jboss server is setup, I believe on MacOS or Linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the first * in the cron should be 0, giving `0 */10 * * * *` meaning run every ten minutes at 0 seconds, rather than run every 10 minutes on *every* second (it will run multiple times depending on how long it takes to complete each invokation. To get 8 invokations, a single run would be just over a minute).  Notice how the [spring javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html) examples begin with a zero.